# Should roles be checked in the domain or UI layer?

Tags: security, domain-driven-design

In the world of DDD, is it right to check user roles in the domain or is that supposed to happen in the UI? The reason I ask is because it seems like, if security and roles are part of the business requirements, it seems like they should live in the domain. However, almost all examples of role checks show it being done in the UI layer. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are a few reasons the concerns of authentication and authorization are handled at the application or UI level:

From a modeling perspective, these concerns often aren't inherent to the capabilities of a system.  For example, a user story might state: "*As an operator, I can turn on the machine ...*".  While it might be important to ensure that only operators are able to access the machine, the machine itself isn't concerned with who can turn it on.

From a pragmatic perspective, these sorts of concerns are often kept separate from the domain to avoid the necessity of injecting application or domain level services into entities.  Since entities are often serialized via an ORM framework, injecting services into entities can be troublesome (see http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/14/injecting-services-into-entities/ for more on this topic).

Comment: What if you're dealing with a root like "Operator". It has behavior on it like `operator.TurnOnMachine()`. Operator might have a list of claims/roles as well. The `TurnOnMachine()` method could check if `operator` has necessary claims and allow if the right claim exists (claim='I can turn off machine.'). While I agree that the machine doesn't know anything about who can turn it on, the operator is the actor here.

Comment: Agreed.  Definitely in the UI.

Comment: The distinction I see here is how one is authorized to use a domain model vs. how one is represented within the domain model.  In some cases, actors may be an inherent and necessary part of your domain (e.g. choosing which character you're going to use in a video game), but this is really a separate concern from any authentication/authorization needs.  Most business applications serve to model the objects or processes a user interacts with, not the user themselves.